# Error when updating an entity with a DatabaseGenerated FK in an EF 6 code first project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I added a foreign key in an EF6 project for an existing property which is annotated with

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

VS generated a migration for it and the FK was added to the DB. I used the FK in a query as intended. All seemed well.

Later, an update of an instance of the entity containing that property resulted in this error: "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column.". Does EF6 not support an FK like this? A SO answer I found suggested not, but I can't find any MS documentation that says this. If this is not supported by EF, why does it add the FK to the database and use the relationship in queries?

Edit 1: The FK is optional (i.e. nullable). New instances always have this as null. An SP runs under certain circumstances and sets it to point to it's related instance. I'm not sure if it's relevant but it is a reference to a different row in the same table.

Edit 2: The code below is simplified. CloneID and AutoCloneID are both self-references. ClonedID may be set by users in the application. AutoCloneID is set by a stored procedure. My changes were a) the public virtual BaseProperty line  b) the 3 lines added to OnModelCreating.

```
    public class BaseProperty
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        
        public int? CloneID { get; set; }             
        public virtual BaseProperty Clone { get; set; }
        
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int? AutoCloneID { get; set; }
        public virtual BaseProperty AutoClone { get; set; }
    }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseProperty>()
        .HasOptional(p => p.AutoClone)
        .WithMany();
    }
```

With the changes I made, updating and saving BaseProperty in the application is usually fine. The error occurs when CloneID is updated in the application. I want to emphasise that a migration to create the new FK works and an EF query using it works.

Edit 3: The error does not occur if when saving after changing CloneID I set AutoCloneID to null. Why? With that change I seem to have a working FK in contradiction to the error message.

Edit 4: The reason for using the attribute is to exclude AutoCloneID from migrations that will allow the application to interfere with the value assigned to it by an internal database stored procedure. The application uses stored procedures for DML. If the attribute is removed then a migration will be created to generate new insert and update stored procedures that will include AutoCloneID.

Edit 5: I discovered another place in the app where the error occurred and setting AutoCloneID to null again supressed it. It's value is irrelevant in database updates because the property is ignored (because of the DatabaseGenerated annotation).

Answer (score 0):

The value of the Foreign Key (in a child table) points to the corresponding row in the parent table, according the etablished relationship. So from the Book, we can reach the Author, from the Post we can reach the Blog, and so on...

If You set this value like "**database computed value**", then every time You update the child row (the Book), or insert a new one, a new value will be calculated for the FK from the database engine... and I don't think that makes any sense, because a new FK value will not necessarily point to a row that exists in the parent table, and hence the error.

Comment: The FK is optional. It is always null initially.

Comment: I tried your code. When I set AutoCloneID to any value, the same identical error appears (adding or updating item). But, if Your read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations), is written that if a value is "database computed", then it must be calculated from the database engine, or specified from You in the "OnModelCreating" section (the article is for EF Core...).

Comment: If You remove the data annotation "DatabaseGenerated...", adding ".HasForeignKey(p => p.AutoCloneID);" in your model, You will be on the right way, because You will have a self-referencing editable foreign key.

Comment: AutoCloneID is set by a stored procedure, never a user in the applicaiton. I do not want the application to change its value. That is why [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] is used. If I remove it then the application will change the column.

Comment: I should add that updates and inserts are done with stored procedures. So, If I remove the attribute, a migration will be generated that includes AutoCloneID in these stored procedures. The result will be to interfere with the value assigned to it by the internal database stored procedure. The application must not change its value.

Comment: Ok. Data annotation is necessary. If I search a row already created and having AutoCloneID not null, and I update CloneID with a new value, it run fine without errors. I used this code: var myMod = db.BaseProperties.Find(1); myMod.CloneID = 2; db.Entry(myMod).State = EntityState.Modified; db.SaveChanges();